# Receive call back is not getting triggered for example.py

Tags: chirp

Send command works fine and it prints what are the numbers that got printed. However, receive call back is not getting called.

Any help on this will be really appreciated.

```
Sending: [249, 63, 158, 86, 23, 21, 39, 137, 161, 112, 226, 11, 139, 148, 134, 115, 216, 214, 155, 204, 88, 13, 100, 193, 55, 181, 241, 120, 85, 105, 201, 63, 152, 58, 10, 227, 214, 50, 175, 246, 76, 44, 26, 56, 232, 50, 108, 139, 208, 67, 251, 202, 120, 181, 3, 17, 106, 132, 46, 12, 30, 55, 223, 233, 12, 2] [ch0]
...........................................................State changed from Sending to Running
Sent: [249, 63, 158, 86, 23, 21, 39, 137, 161, 112, 226, 11, 139, 148, 134, 115, 216, 214, 155, 204, 88, 13, 100, 193, 55, 181, 241, 120, 85, 105, 201, 63, 152, 58, 10, 227, 214, 50, 175, 246, 76, 44, 26, 56, 232, 50, 108, 139, 208, 67, 251, 202, 120, 181, 3, 17, 106, 132, 46, 12, 30, 55, 223, 233, 12, 2] [ch0]
..................................................................................................................
```

Had to force close the script here.

Comment: Can you paste the entire output of the example script? You should have a list of all of the available audio i/o devices.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an issue with the audio input from your microphone. You should notice a list of audio input devices printed to the console when you start the script, make sure the arrow is pointing to the correct device.

You can specific the input device using the `-i` argument. So `-i 2` would select the device with index equal to 2.

Secondly, I would recommend checking the input audio by putting the SDK into debug mode. This will record the input audio to a file, for further information see https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/python#debugging